# several norms on a vector space

Tags: normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Suppose that we have a real infinite dimensional vector space and several norms, pseudonorms or seminorms (please note here that I do not know what is the technical difference between semi- and pseudo-) but anyway, if there are several of them, how can we construct some natural topology with their help ? Are there more choices how to get a well defined topology from them ?

Comment: I mean, each norm induces a metric, and each metric a topology generated by the open balls in said metric. Not sure if you're looking for something else that somehow interweaves multiple norms at once

Comment: @PrincessEev So to claim that some subset is open it suffice exactly that it is open by at least one member of that norm possibilities is that correct ?

Comment: I think there may be a misunderstanding Each norm induces its own topology; a set may be open in the topology induced by one norm, but not open in the topology induced by another norm.

Comment: @AlexS My problem is [this](https://books.google.cz/books?id=bvuRuwuFBWwC&pg=PA147&dq=functional+analysis+reed+is+fairly+simple&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjonaveiuD5AhVYs6QKHcWUBloQ6AF6BAgFEAI#v=onepage&q=generated%20by%20norms&f=false) On the page 147 they say: "Put the Frechet topology on something generated by a family of norms". So how can I obtain their topology thus generated; can it be explained in some technical detail  ?

Comment: The "natural" topology induced by norms or seminorms can be understood as the coarsest topology that makes this norm continuous wrt. the canonical topology on $\mathbb R$. Similiarly we could understand the "natural" topology induced by a family of norms as the coarses topology that makes all of these norms continuous, that is the coarsest common refinement of the topologies induced by each norm.

Comment: You take the topology where convergence is given by convergence in each norm simultaneously.

Comment: @Lazy The explanation I was looking for. What is the difference between semi- and pseudo- norm ? I understand that "Pseudo" omits the positive defintiveness from ordinary norm. What about semi-norm ?

Comment: @user122424 A seminorm is a norm without definiteness. A pseudonorm is a norm with the absolute homogenity replaces by absolute subhomogenity (so $\leq$ instead of $=$).

Comment: @Lazy These are not consistent definitions. In differential geometry  a **pseudo**-riemanian manifold is what you call **semi-** while the word **pseudo** is still present in that manifold.

Comment: @Lazy BTW, are norm and positive definitive symmetric billinear map equivalent in some sense ?

Comment: @user122424 Only in one direction. A positive definite symmetric bilinear map is something called an *inner product*. If $T:V^2\to\mathbb R$ is positive definite and symmetric and bilinear then $\sqrt{T(x,x)}$ defines a norm on $V$, as $T(x+y,x+y) = T(x,x) + T(y,y) + T(x,y) + T(y,x) = T(x, x) + T(y,y) + 2T(x,y) \leq T(x,x) + T(y,y) + 2\sqrt{T(x,x)T(y,y)}$ (where we use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $|T(x,y)|\leq \sqrt{T(x,x)}\sqrt{T(y,y)}$.